# Xamarin web services Unit test

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin

Can you please suggest how to write unit test for web services in xamarin forms, I am getting error to on running

```
    [TestFixture()]
    public class LeadRepositoryTest
    {
        private Mock<ILeadWebService> mockLeadWebService { get; set; }
        private Mock<ILeadDatabaseService> mockLeadDatabaseService { get; set; }
        private LeadService leadRepository { get; set; }

        public LeadRepositoryTest()
        {
            var repository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default) { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Empty };
            mockLeadWebService = repository.Create<ILeadWebService>().As<ILeadWebService>();
            mockLeadDatabaseService = repository.Create<ILeadDatabaseService>().As<ILeadDatabaseService>();
            mockLeadWebService.Setup(x => x.GetNormalLeads(CommonMockData.GetLeadRequestParams())).Returns(Task.FromResult(OperationResult.CreateSuccessResult(new GetLeadsApiResponseDTO())));
            leadRepository = new LeadService(mockLeadDatabaseService.Object, mockLeadWebService.Object, null, null);
        }

        [Test()]
        public async void GetNormalLeads_WebServiceIsNotNull()
        {
            //Arrange
            var parameters = new LeadRequestParams()
            {
                Offset = 0,
                Limit = 20,
                PageName = "Today",
           };

            //Act
            var operationResult = await leadRepository.GetNormalLeads(parameters);
            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(operationResult?.Data);

        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you provide your error?

Comment: application getting crashed shown in below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really need is:

```
var mockLeadRepository = new Mock<ILeadService>();
mockLeadRepository.Setup(x => x.GetNormalLeads(It.IsAny<Object>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(OperationResult.CreateSuccessResult(new GetLeadsApiResponseDTO())));
leadRepository = mockLeadRepository.Object;
```

Comment: No, Only test case getting fails

Comment: Try to set up Breakpoints at you constructor and in the first line of your test method.

Comment: already done, but can you provide me any sample,
email - shashikant0423@gmail.com